# ImportError: No module named AppHome

Tags: django

I have created a `Django` project by name `PrjDjangoProject` and an app named `AppHome`.

I have ensured all entries in :

```
1. settings.py->INSTALLED-APPS 
2. urls.py entries in both.
3.I have also checked PYTHONPATH variable to hold the physical path of both
```

However I get an error - `ImportError: No module named 'AppHome'`

Comment: can you put your code on..

Comment: Let us check, place your settings file and your folder structure.